# Resursive function doesn't return all elements

Tags: php, recursion

I have really dumb question, but I'm looking at that code since half hour and can't figure out how to solve it.

I'm working on some more complex iterator, but I'll show problem on that simple example:

```
public function test($obj = null)
{
    $test = array(
        'Level 1 A' => array(
            'Level 2 A' => 1,
            'Level 2 B' => array(
                'Level 3 A' => 2,
                'Level 4 B' => 3,
            )
        ),
        'Level 1 B' => array(
            'Level 2 C' => 4
        )
    );

    if ($obj) {
        $test = $obj;
    }


    foreach ($test as $key => $value) {
        var_dump($key);
        if (is_array($value)) {
            return $this->test($value);
        }
    }

    return $value;
}
```

Problem is that this function doesn't output `Level 1 B` and child elements. 
I know that this is very newbie problem, but I need someone with fresh look on that.

Comment: What is this function supposed to do? Also "return" will exit the whole function, so only the first key is processed.

Comment: It should iterate through all elements in array, but I don't want to use any standard iterator, bcuz I need this solution for more complex work

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

The return statement in the foreach loop will end the recursion after it encounters the first array() so the second array will not be processed.

Comment: Yes, I know that but I don't know how to fix it. Do I need another function? Or is it possible to do it with just single function?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need a recursive [generator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php).

This function will move through your data structure and return all values it encounters:

```
function iterate($data) {
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            yield from iterate($value);
        }
        else {
            yield $value;
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
foreach (iterate($test) as $value) {
    // do something with $value
}
```